# One-dimensional Hamiltonian in SUSY Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, supersymmetry

I've seen in many places, in "Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics" of F. Cooper for example, that the hamiltonian in one dimension is defined:
$$\hat H_1=\hat A^\dagger\hat A=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V_1(x)$$
with
$$\hat A = \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x) \qquad \hat A^\dagger = -\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x)$$
Later on, they identify $V_1(x)$ as:
$$V_1(x)=W^2(x)-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}W'(x).$$
I was doing the math and if I calculate $\hat H_1$ i reach to the following,
$$\hat H_1 = \hat A^\dagger\hat A = \left[-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x)\right]\left[\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x)\right]=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}W'(x)+W^2(x)+W(x)\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}$$
According to this there is a extra term, does that mean that $W(x)\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}=0$? And if it's that the case, why is that $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Not really, since you apply the operator $\hat{A}^\dagger \hat{A}$ on a function, one need to pay attention to derivative, in other words

$$\hat H_1\Phi(x) = \hat A^\dagger\hat A\Phi(x) \\= \left[-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x)\right]\left[\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}+W(x)\right]\Phi(x)\\=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Phi(x)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}W(x)\Phi(x)\right)+W^2(x)\Phi(x)+W(x)\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\frac{d}{dx}\Phi(x)\\=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Phi(x)-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}W'(x)\Phi(x)+W^2(x)\Phi(x)\\=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}W'(x)+W^2(x)\right)\Phi(x)$$