# Deducing the ground state from a known first excited state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I am studying Schrodinger equation with a potential of hyberpolic functions.
$$ H \psi = - \psi''(x) + \Big[1-\frac{12}{1+b \cosh{(2x)}} + \frac{15\,(1-b^2)}{[1+b \cosh{(2x)}]^2}\Big]\psi(x) $$

The first excited state is known $ \psi(x) = \sinh{(2x)}\,[1+b \cosh{(2x)}]^{-3/2} $ and can be seen to have eigenvalue $ E = 0 $. However, there should be a ground state to this potential. Can I deduce the ground state from knowing the wavefunction of the first excited state?

Numerical solutions on this potential (in python) give nonsensical eigenvalues, so I am trying to find the groundstate (semi)analytically.

Comment: What do you mean nonsense eigenvalues? A ground state can be computed with Mathematica function `NDEigensystem[]` . For $b=1/2$ it gives $E=-1.47336$ on $-10\le x\le 10$.

Comment: May I ask how on earth you found the excited state?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I get {0.00990586, 0.990966, 1.03495, 1.12597, 1.30788} as the first five eigenvalues for b = 0.5 which omits the ground state and starts from the first state.

Comment: @MattHanson The system I am studying has to have a zero mode that is given by the first derivative of a classical configuration (This is related to the translation of said configuration).

Comment: @MattHanson At $E=0$ we have $\psi=\frac{\tanh (x) \sqrt{\tanh ^2(x)-1}}{\left((b-1) \tanh ^2(x)+b+1\right)^{3/2}}$

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/679476/one-dimensional-hamiltonian-in-susy-quantum-mechanics?rq=1)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I tried SUSYQM methods. The superpotential is $$ -2 \coth{(2x)} + \frac{3b \sinh{(2x)}}{1+b\cosh{(2x)}} $$ which gives $ E_0 = -8 $. This is less than the minimum of the potential!!

Comment: @MohamedS.Mahdi What domain you used to compute eigenvalues at b=1/2?

Comment: See [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pöschl–Teller_potential) and  Lekner, J., (2007) Reflectionless eigenstates of the sech2 potential. *American Journal of Physics* **75** (12), pp.1151-1157.

Comment: [Furthermore](https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/20/13/017).

Comment: @AlexTrounev The snippet   {vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[H, \[Phi][x], {x, -10, 10}, 2]  
  vals = {0.00990586, 0.990966}  where H is the Hamiltonian as given in the question. Also the functions given are not smooth, so they are problematic.

Comment: @MohamedS.Mahdi With Mathematica we have `b = 1/2; h = 10; sol = 
 Sort[Transpose[NDEigensystem[{H, DirichletCondition[psi[x] == 0, True]}, 
    psi[x], {x, -h, h}, 10]], #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]`. Solution looks nice and first 2 states are $E=-1.47336, 0.00990603$. For `b=1/3` we have $E=-0.81439, 0.00780259 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *b*=1, your problem reduces to the well-known [Pöschl–Teller potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential), shifted by a unit, so your excited state has
$$
\psi''= \left (1-{2(2+1)\over \cosh^2(x)}\right )\psi,
$$
alright.

And then the ground state, the only other bound state of it,  *must* be proportional to $P^2_2(\tanh (x))$, proportional to
$$
\psi_0= 1/\cosh^2(x), ~~~\leadsto \\
\psi_0''= \left(1+3 -6/\cosh^2(x) \right )\psi_0.
$$

You might consider doing perturbation theory in (*b-1*)...

Comment: Is it normal that we can get a specific state exactly, while the other states are only obtained perturbatively?!

Comment: I'm not sure. For arbitrary *b*, you might be able to adapt the powerful methods of the link papers. What is expected is that for b "close" to 1, you'd just have two bound states continuously deformed from the exactly solvable and reflectionless P-T case...